# RTE always on text mode by default

Tags: visual-editor, text

I have installed a theme with visual composer on my wordpress and everything was working fine until I added a widget above the header.

From that moment on, every time I want to create a new entry the RTE is always on text mode instead of visual.

I find it really weird that my customization have caused this, does anyone has another explanation and/or solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really think of a reason for the behaviour, maybe it is just a bug in the theme, of course I can't say anything specific without knowing the code. But you should be able get around it by making use of the `wp_default_editor` hook and explicitly set the type of editor you want to show first, which is inside the function with the same name, so [`wp_default_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_default_editor/).

```
function wpse194059_set_wp_default_editor( $editor ) {
  // possible values are: 
  // tinymce - visual mode
  // html - text mode
  return 'tinymce';
}
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'wpse194059_set_wp_default_editor' );
```

Comment: It sounds good but where do I add that code? functions.php?

Comment: I applied the code you provided on functions.php and the system is now loading up first the visual editor but it changes automatically to the text editor. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Can't tell exactly, as said, it might be some bug with your theme or a plug-in. @viriato

Comment: I have been googling about this and trying to find all possible solutions and applying. The result is still the same no matter what i do. Is there a way to overwrite this?